# Report Builder Create New Column Instead Of Page

Tags: sql, reportbuilder

I am using report builder to generate letters. What I'm trying to do is have one column of values but when it reaches the end of the page, instead of creating a new page I want it to overflow to a new column to the right of the first. Alternatively, it would work if it populated the data across multiple columns before creating a new row.

Is this something that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to find a work around from the sql stored procedure area as a tablix in SSRS is based on the dataset retrieved and this is not a feature or work around in report builder.

I suggest you attempt to create a stored procedure that does this manipulation for you to a set number or columns and test this out for set number of rows. This will have to be taylored to your sql platform.

Good luck I love your requirement and question!

Answer (score 1):

I would go for workaround:
Basicly the solution is to define the query to display your data in columns (for instance column A - values 1-60, column B - values 61-120...).

Then you can define each column as different dataset.

In the SSRS you can define number of tables (each tables will contain only one column) and to place them next to each other. (using the table visibility to hide the `null` tables)

**Lets get started:**

First you need to know how many rows are fitting one page (for this example lets say 60).

Next you need to know what is the max values you can have (for this example lets say 180).

Define your query according to the following:

```
WITH NumberedMyTable AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        MyTable
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Value
FROM
    NumberedMyTable
WHERE
    RowNumber BETWEEN @From AND @To
```

Repeat this query for every column (for this example you will need to define this query 3 times).

then define 3 tables - one column each, and define each dataset as their values accordingly.

Define the tablix visibility expression as following:
`=IIf(CountRows("MyDataset") = 0,false,true)`

**That it!**